# Some definitions: parskip, baselineskip, topskip

Tags: spacing, parskip

I am a bit confused about what characteristics of the page are controlled by: `\parskip`, `\baselineskip`, `\topskip`.`

\parskip` controls the space between paragraphs but is it the same value all across the document? It seems, for example, to have a different value in a paragraph between title and subtitle that in one between subtitle and text. Is this right?

Are there simple ways to control all different “parskips” in the `.tex` file?

Some examples about those three will be welcome.

Comment: The term paragraph here does not denote a sectional unit with a title, but a unit of ordinary text that TeX splits in lines. Usually, there's no parskip, but paragraph are made distinct by a small indentation of the first line of the paragraph called `\parindent`.

Comment: @Bernard haven't read this comment. Thanks Bernard

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`\parskip` adds some "glue" between each paragraph. As I understand it, "glue" in LaTeX means, that it is not something fixed but it can adapt a bit according to what fills the space on a page best. This vertical empty space is inserted between every paragraph but not before the first or after the last one on a page. But it does influence the spacing between eg. a section heading and the beginning of the text.
There is a package called [`parskip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) which should be used if you want to use spacing between paragraphs instead of indentation in the standard classes like `article`.

`\baselineskip` influences the spaceing between two lines. But if you want to change the linespreading you should instead use the package [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) because that changes the linespacing for text but excludes captions, footnotes etc. from the setting which is normally wanted.

`\topskip` specifies the vertical spacing of the first line of a page in relation to the default.

`\parindent`  by default LaTeX indents every paragraph except from the first one after a new heading. The indentation of the other paragraphs can be changed with this command.

---

For comparison lets look at a default `\documentclass{article}` in LaTeX (with the package `showframe` to visualise the separation at the top)

[image]

and one where we set

```
\topskip=40pt
\parskip=10pt
\parindent=0pt
\baselineskip=15pt
```

[image]

Comment: I think you meant topskip not topsep (and better to say it specifies the first baseline on the page rather than it adds space)

Comment: `\parindent` is a TeX feature. See the TeXbook page 474.