# bigskip on every new paragraph with latex

Tags: spacing

I prefer the look with `\bigskip`. How can I make this the default so I don't need to type it after every paragraph.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371983/some-definitions-parskip-baselineskip-topskip#371986
This may help you. In particular play with \parskip.

Comment: use the `parskip` package this adds the vertical skip after paragraphs and then accounts for some skips you don't want around internal paragraphs in section headings and lists etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd give

```
\addtolength\parskip{\bigskipamount}
```

a try.

---

The following compilable example shows (a) that both `\parskip` and `\bigskipamount` are *rubber* lengths by default and (b) that adding two rubber lengths produces, sure enough, another rubber length.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\begin{document}
\the\bigskipamount % show value of \bigskipamount

\the\parskip % show value of \parskip
\hrule
\lipsum[1][1-4] \par \lipsum[1][5-9] % output two short paragraphs

\addtolength\parskip{\bigskipamount}
\the\parskip % show value of \parskip again
\hrule
\lipsum[1][1-4] \par \lipsum[1][5-9] % output two short paragraphs
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I control the amout in bigskip? Also before it looked good before itemize  without bigskip but now these parts have too much space... But I guess this is a new problem :-)

Comment: @David - To revert the amount of whitespace above `itemize` environments to its default (compact) value, I suggest you (a) load the `enumitem` package and (b) change `\begin{itemize}` to `\begin{itemize}[before=\vspace{-\bigskipamount}]`.

Comment: @David - You asked, "How can I control the amout in bigskip"? How about `\setlength\bigskipamount{8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}`. Actually, since `\bigskip` may be used by various low-level TeX and LaTeX routines, I would *not* change the default value of `\bigskipamount`. Instead, I'd define a new length via, say, `\newlength\mybigskipamount`, and then apply `\setlength` to that new parameter: `\setlength\mybigskipamount{8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `parskip` package.

```
% parskipprob.tex  SE 568299

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=\bigskipamount,indent]{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```